# Node class is an internal class in my code?

Tags: java, class

I'm asked this question and I'm not really sure what it means,

> In our LinkedList class, the Node class is an internal class. Briefly
> describe two things that would have to be coded differently if the
> Node class was a separate class from the LinkedList class.

Here's the code for my LinkedList class:

```java
public class LinkedList<T> implements LinkedListInterface<T> {
  private Node head;
  private Node tail;
  private int count;

  public LinkedList() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    count = 0;
  }

  class Node {
    T data;
    Node next;

    Node(T data) {
      this.data = data;
      next = null;
    }
  }

  public Node getHead() {
    return head;
  }

  public int add(T item) {
    Node newNode = new Node(item);
    if (isEmpty()) {
      head = newNode;
    } else {
      tail.next = newNode;
    }
    tail = newNode;
    count++;
    return count;
  }

  public void add(T item, int pos) throws ListException {
    if (pos < 1 || pos > count + 1) {
      throw new ListException("Invalid position to insert at");
    }
    Node newNode = new Node(item);
    if (count == 0) {
      add(item);
    } else if (pos == count + 1) {
      add(item);
    } else if (pos == 1) {
      newNode.next = head;
      head = newNode;
      count++;
    } else {
      Node prev = jump(pos - 2);
      newNode.next = prev.next;
      prev.next = newNode;
      count++;
    }
  }

  private Node jump(int numJumps) {
    Node nd = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < numJumps; i++) {
      nd = nd.next;
    }
    return nd;
  }

  public LinkedList<T> combine(LinkedList<T> obj2) {
    Node list1 = this.getHead();
    Node list2 = obj2.getHead();
    if (list2 == null) {
      return this;
    }
    if(list1==null) {
      return obj2;
    }
    
    Node temp=list1;
    while(temp.next!=null) {
      temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next=list2;
    return this;
  }

  public int contains(T item) {
    Node nd = this.head;
    for (int pos = 1; pos <= count; pos++) {
      if (nd.data.equals(item)) {
        return pos;
      }
      nd = nd.next;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  public LinkedList<T> copy() {
    LinkedList<T> l = new LinkedList<T>();
    try {
      for (int pos = 1; pos <= count; pos++)
        l.add(retrieve(pos));
    }
    catch(ListException e) {
      System.out.println("Should not occur (Copy)");
    }
    return l;
  }

  public boolean equals(Object list) {
    if (list == null) {
      return false;
    }
    LinkedList myLinkedList = (LinkedList)list;
    if(myLinkedList.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    if(myLinkedList.length() != this.length()) {
      return false;
    }
    try{
      for (int pos = 1; pos <= count; pos++) {
        if(!myLinkedList.retrieve(pos).equals(this.retrieve(pos))) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    catch (ListException e) {
      System.out.println("Should not occur");
    }
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return length() == 0;
  }

  public int length() {
    return count;
  }
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

  public T remove(int pos) throws ListException {
    if (pos < 1 || pos > count) {
      throw new ListException("Invalid position to remove from");
    }
    Node removedItem = null;
    if (count == 1) {
      removedItem = head;
      head = null;
      tail = null;
    } else if (pos == 1) {
      removedItem = head;
      head = head.next;
    } else if (pos == count) {
      removedItem = tail;
      Node prev = jump(pos - 2);
      prev.next = null;
      tail = prev;
    } else {
      Node prev = jump(pos - 2);
      removedItem = prev.next;
      prev.next = prev.next.next;
    }
    count--;
    return removedItem.data;
  }

  public int remove(T item) {
    int numRemoved = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    try {
      while ((pos = contains(item)) > 0) {
        remove(pos);
        numRemoved++;
      }
    } catch (ListException e){
      System.out.print(e);
    }
    return numRemoved;
  }

  int find_length(Node list){
    int count = 0;
    while (list!=null) {
      count++;
      list=list.next;
    }
    return count;
  }
  public void replace(T item, int pos) throws ListException {
    if (pos < 1 || pos > count + 1) {
      throw new ListException("Invalid position to replace at");
    }
    Node list = this.getHead();
    int length = find_length(list);
    if(pos<1||pos>length){
      return;
    }
    while(list!=null){
      pos--;
      if(pos==0){
        list.data=item;
        return;
      }
      list=list.next;
    }
  }
  

  public T retrieve(int pos) throws ListException {
    T item = null;
    if (pos < 1 || pos > count) {
    throw new ListException("Invalid position to retrieve from");
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
    return head.data;
    }
    Node prev = jump(pos - 2);
    item = prev.next.data;
    return item;
  }

  public LinkedList<T> reverse() {
    LinkedList<T> l = new LinkedList<T>();
    try {
      for (int pos = count; pos > 0; pos--)
        l.add(retrieve(pos));
    }
    catch (ListException e) {
      System.out.println("Should not occur (Reverse)");
    }
    return l;
  }
    public String toString() {
       String temp = "";
       Node nd = head;
       while (nd != null) {
          temp += nd.data + "-";
          nd = nd.next;
       }
       return temp;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to get is the since the Node class is located in the same class as my LinkedList class, it is referred to as an internal class. If it were to be separate, would I have to implement a Node class similarly to the LinkedListInterface<T> class? What else would have to be coded differently?

Comment: [1] `private`, [2] inner classes get to refer to an instance of their outer implicitly. make it a separate class and you'd either have to make a field for that, or figure out a way to do without.

Comment: Move the class Node outside and compile your code.  If it compiles and runs as expected, then there's no change needed.  Otherwise, ask yourself, what do you need to do to make it work if the node class is outside?

Comment: It is an **inner** class. Java has no concept called *internal* class.